# How to get XBRL into MySQL database?

Tags: sql, finance

I am trying to retrieve SEC filings in XBRL and dump them into MySQL. Anyone know how to do this or who I can hire to do it?

Comment: Is there a specific part of the XBRL (XML) that you're looking to extract? Here is some Ruby code on Github that writes some of the fields to CSV: https://github.com/ea54595/XbrlReader/blob/5426e77896d8b1b4e1c05758aee63974f282ffa4/FinancialData/FinancialData.rb#L25